# Shiny "updateCheckboxGroupInput" inconsistency

Tags: shiny

I don't know if this is a bug of just a feature, but the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` function in Shiny is not working consistently. When I update the group with `selected=FALSE` to deselect all the choices, the related reactive components (observer, UI elements) doesn't change anything. I know that there are many ways to do this task, my point here is to show the lack of consistency of the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` with the `selected` parameter.

Here is simplified example that represents the problem using a couple of action buttons to select/deselect all the choices on the group. After updating with `selected=FALSE`, all the choices are deselected but the change does not affect the reactive components associated (in this case verbatimTextOutput) as is the case of selecting all.

Can someone explain me why the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` is not working as expected?

```
  choices <- letters[1:5]
  runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
      checkboxGroupInput('chkGrp', 'Options', choices),
      actionButton("all","All"),
      actionButton("none","None"),
      verbatimTextOutput("value")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
       output$value <- renderPrint({ input$chkGrp })
       observe({
          if ( is.null(input$all) || input$all == 0)
               return()
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"chkGrp",selected=choices )
       })
       observe({
          if ( is.null(input$none) || input$none == 0)
               return()
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"chkGrp",selected=FALSE)
       })
    }
  ))
```

Comment: what happens if you set `selected=NULL`

Comment: If you set `selected=NULL` it doesn't deselect the check boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` you still have to provide what goes in there.

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
choices <- letters[1:5]
runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    checkboxGroupInput('chkGrp', 'Options', choices),
    actionButton("all","All"),
    actionButton("none","None"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$chkGrp })
    observe({
      if ( is.null(input$all) || input$all == 0)
        return()
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"chkGrp",selected=choices )
    })
    observe({
      if ( is.null(input$none) || input$none == 0)
        return()
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"chkGrp",choices = choices,selected=NULL)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solve the problem, but I'm still wondering why if all the boxes are deselected using only the `selected` parameter and the `input$chkGrp` is returning `NULL`, the `output$value` is not updated?

Comment: Not able to edit right now but if you read the docs for `updateCheckboxGroupInput` it says to use `selected = character(0)` to clear the selections. If you do that you don't need to supply the choices