# Shiny updateCheckboxInputGroup

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble with updateCheckboxGroupInput not actually updating the input (in time) for my following observers to react.

When experimenting I found some results that puzzle me (a lot), and I hope somebody can enlighten me. Both of the following code snippets are variations on the code provided in the shiny help for the function.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The first checkbox group controls the second"),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",
                     c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup2", "Input checkbox 2",
                     c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent({input$inCheckboxGroup},{
  print(input$inCheckboxGroup2)
  x <- input$inCheckboxGroup

  # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
  if (is.null(x))
   x <- character(0)

  # Can also set the label and select items
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "inCheckboxGroup2",
                           label = paste("Checkboxgroup label", length(x)),
                           choices =  c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C"),
                           selected = x
  )
  print(input$inCheckboxGroup2)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run this code using **observeEvent()** and check boxes in the first group of boxes both "print" give me the selection previous to the change (although one print is before and one after the updateCheckboxGroupInput). Correspondingly (I think) following observeEvents wrongly use the wrong input.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The first checkbox group controls the second"),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",
                     c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup2", "Input checkbox 2",
                     c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
  print(input$inCheckboxGroup2)
  x <- input$inCheckboxGroup

  # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
  if (is.null(x))
   x <- character(0)

  # Can also set the label and select items
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "inCheckboxGroup2",
                           label = paste("Checkboxgroup label", length(x)),
                           choices =  c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C"),
                           selected = x
  )
  print(input$inCheckboxGroup2)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run this code using **observe** and check boxes in the first group of boxes both "print" give me the selection after the change (although one print is before and one after the updateCheckboxGroupInput).

Why does this happen? And what can I do with observeEvent to make sure that the updated values are used by subsequent event observers?

My question is related to this question asked a while ago:

[Shiny "updateCheckboxGroupInput" inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316578/shiny-updatecheckboxgroupinput-inconsistency)

The answer there did not help me. Setting the selected argument to character(0) did not change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to checkbox inputs. It's not a bug either, although it certainly can seem like the wrong behaviour. I won't go into the details and this answer might not satisfy you because it's a very TLDR, but essentially When you call the update function, it doesn't happen immediately, it happens on the next flush. You're telling shiny to update the input, then you're printing the input but the update hasn't happened yet. I agree it's not intuitive and sometimes it's annoying because you want to be able to use the same value that you just updated to. I filed an issue with shiny a long time ago so see if there's a way to control that behaviour, if I find it I'll add a link.

EDIT: I was wrong, I didn't file a bug, but I did discuss this on the shiny google group 2 years ago https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/uSJXD8IBpkY/RpJo2wBzRrMJ